Why it is not showing the data that I give them instead it show the word post
I am new to Spring Boot, I hope someone will answer my question. When I run the program, it shows the words post instead of the data I give them
My pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>tmang.luvtocode</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

My RestController file
package tmang.luvtocode.demo.controller;


//import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import tmang.luvtocode.demo.domain.Post;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/posts")
public class PostController {
    
    @GetMapping 
    public String postPage(Model model){
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle("Hello Spring Boot");
        post.setDescription("Spring Boot");
        post.setBody("Spring Boot is Awesome");
        model.addAttribute("post", post);
        return "post";
    }
}

My data comment class
package tmang.luvtocode.demo.domain;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Comment {
   private Integer id;
   private String title;
   private String authorName;
   private String body;
   private LocalDateTime createdOn;
   private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
}

My data Post class
package tmang.luvtocode.demo.domain;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Post {
      private Integer id;
      private String title;
      private String description;
      private String body;
      private String slug;
      private PostStatus postStatus;
      private LocalDateTime createdOn;
      private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
      private List<Comment> comments;
}

My enum PostStatus
package tmang.luvtocode.demo.domain;

public enum PostStatus {
   DRAFT,PUBLISHED
}

My post.html file which is inside template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spring Blog</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Spring Blog</h1>

    <h3 th:text="${post.title}"></h3>
    <h6 th:text="${post.description}"></h6>
    <div th:text="{post.body}"></div>
</body>

</html>

I don't know what the cause of the problem that is it print the word post instead of the data I give them. Hope someone can solve the problems for me. THanks

This is because your controller layer returns a string "post" instead of the post object

Then how am I going to print the post?

Remove the "" in the return value of the controller layer and change it to  return post.return "post " -> return post

Use @Controller instead of @RestController. @RestController is for returning content as is (or json/xml) and thus it will just show post. Use @Controller is for resolving a view named post which is what you want.

It is because you are using @RestController instead of @Controller annotation.
When using @RestController, the value returned is not treated as the view name, but Spring tries to convert the return value to JSON or text.
Solution: change annotation to @Controller
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/posts")
public class PostController {
    
    @GetMapping 
    public String postPage(Model model){
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle("Hello Spring Boot");
        post.setDescription("Spring Boot");
        post.setBody("Spring Boot is Awesome");
        model.addAttribute("post", post);
        return "post";
    }
}


This is because your controller layer returns a string "post" instead of the post object.
package tmang.luvtocode.demo.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/posts")
public class PostController {
    
    @GetMapping 
    public String postPage(Model model){
       ....
        return post;
    }
}


You're wrong. First, he is working with template engine, hence returning a Post does not make sense. Second, You cannot return Post object from a method of type of String.
